# session timeout not working properly in global.asax

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net project I have an event in global.asax as session end which fires when the session is timeout and in this event, I am calling one stored procedure that updates logout time and flag in the table. But when the user is log in and after some work user close browser and on next day when he tries to log in at first attempt message shows that user is already login but when he tried to log in again he is able to log in.

**please help its production issue**.

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Admin.User_Role objUserRole = new Admin.User_Role();

    objUserRole.SchemaName = 
(string)CBase.TripleDESDecode(Application["SchemaName"].ToString(), 
CBase.EncryptionKey);
    if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        objUserRole.UserId = (string)Session["UserId"];

    objUserRole.ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(CBase.GetServerDateTime());

    try
    {
        objUserRole.funcUpdateLoggedIn();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Logout.aspx"), false);
    }
}
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = this.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

}
public HttpSessionState GetSession()
{

    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Session;
    }
}
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{


}
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Admin.User_Role objUserRole = new Admin.User_Role();

    string userid = Convert.ToString(GetSession()["UserId"]);
    objUserRole.UserId = (string)CBase.TripleDESDecode(userid, 
CBase.EncryptionKey);
    objUserRole.ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(CBase.GetServerDateTime());
   // objUserRole.funcUpdateLoggedIn();


    try
    {
        objUserRole.funcUpdateLoggedIn();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Logout.aspx"), false);
    }


   finally 
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();
    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: please remove the commented code from the question and post minimal code which is really matters!

Comment: Did you see the "note" in your Session_End? Also " closing browser" does not end the session (but "next day" should). What is your session timeout?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i removed it ..

Comment: my session timeout is 20 minutes @HansKeﬆing

Comment: What is the expiration timespan on your authentication cookie? I assume you set a FormsAuthentication cookie, when a user logs in. As long as that cookie is valid, the system considers the user logged in.

Comment: @Marco form authentication has been disabled in  my IIS

Comment: How do users log in?

Comment: we used windows authentication

Comment: You cannot acutally logout from your application then and trying to update a logout time in your database is pointless.

Comment: on successfully logout my logout time is updated in database and 'islogged'   flag is reset so on next login this flag is checked .But on next day when user try to login at first attempt it shows user is logged in and on next attempt he able to logged in.